# What is the functionality of additional_attributes from catalog & how it's work

Tags: magento-enterprise, attributes, catalog, php-5.4, wsdl

What is the functionality of additional_attributes from catalog & how it's work?

**catalog->etc->wsdl.xml**

```
<complexType name="catalogProductReturnEntity">
                <all> 
                    <element name="additional_attributes" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
                </all>
            </complexType>

 <message name="catalogProductInfoResponse">
        <part name="info" type="typens:catalogProductReturnEntity"/>
    </message>
```

Can you please explain briefly if it possible give me a example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The product in magento use the EAV paradigm.
This means you can add attributes to products without altering the table schema.
But this also has a side effect. you cannot know at any given point what are the attributes of a product just by the main table structure.
Since attributes can be added by the admins from the UI, there is no way to know what elements to list in the WSDL in order to return their values through the API.
In order to accommodate this, magento lists in the wsdl only a few system attributes of the product like `sku, type, name, description, ...` and provides a way to get the rest of the attribute values via `additional_attributes` that is a list of key-value pairs.

When making the call to `catalogProductInfo` you must provide as input the message `catalogProductInfoRequest` that looks like this:

```
<message name="catalogProductInfoRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="productId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="storeView" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="attributes" type="typens:catalogProductRequestAttributes"/>
    <part name="identifierType" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

Notice the `attributes` part. It has the type `typens:catalogProductRequestAttributes` that is defined like this:

```
       <complexType name="catalogProductRequestAttributes">
            <all>
                <element name="attributes" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="additional_attributes" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
```

what you put in the `additional_attributes` in this parameter, you will get back with values in the `additional_attributes` from the response.